# onchange function get height of div which is getting show hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one selectbox. On the change of value in selectbox div is getting show and hide.

div first has less content and div two has too much content.
If I select from selectbox div first showing and div two hiding and vice versa,
but my requirment is if I select div one I get height of div and instantly and if I select div two I get height of div two on the spot.

```
$("#test").change(function() {
    var j = $("#divfirst").find("body").height();
    var w = $("#divtwo").find("body").height();
    alert(j);
    alert(w);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="divfirst">less content</div>
<div id="divtwo">more content more content</div>
```

Comment: Just `$("#divfirst").height();` will give you div height

Comment: no but i am getting the height of previous div but the current div

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
$("#test").change(function() {
var j = $("#divfirst").css('height').replace('px','');
var w = $("#divtwo").css('height').replace('px','');
 alert(j);
alert(w);
})
```

Or You can use:

```
$("#test").change(function() {
var j = $("#divfirst").offset().height;
var w = $("#divtwo").offset().height;
 alert(j);
alert(w);
})
```

Comment: no actully if i select divfirst and now again change to divtwo then i am getting the height of firstdiv as its currently on dom

Comment: Can you create a fiddle ,